# App.Exe Config Transform with Azure Devops and Release Variables

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am currently using Azure Devops with an local build agent to deploy a windows service to an internal server and am looking for information on how to transform my `MyApp.Exe.config` file using the variables defined in my release task.

With web applications, this seems fairly straightforward.  I have a `parameters.xml` file that is used in conjunction with the `SetParameters File` in my `IIS Web Deploy` task.  This pulls the variables from the release task and updates the web.config accordingly.

However, I can't find a definitive answer on how to do this with a config file for an executable.  [This document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/file-transform?view=azure-devops) suggests that it should be possible, but looks like I'd need to provide a transform file with the variables already set.

In summary, what I am looking to do is use a `Parameters.xml` file to transform the config file of an executable using my release variables.  How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Have you ever found a way to make use of the SetParameters, instead of tokenizing the app.config as suggested in the answer below?

Comment: @devqon no - i just went with the answer below.  It seemed less than ideal, but I haven't thought about again it since last year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unclear in your question which values you're trying to replace in your target file, so it might be important to note:

> **[". . .](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops#xml-variable-substitution)** Variable substitution takes effect only on the applicationSettings, appSettings, connectionStrings, and configSections elements of configuration files. If you are looking to substitute values outside of these elements you can use a (parameters.xml) file, **however you will need to use a 3rd party pipeline task** to handle the variable substitution. **[. . ."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops#xml-variable-substitution)**

### If you can't find a 3rd party task

Of course the [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops#xml-variable-substitution) doesn't point us to any favored 3rd party task. So if you can't find a task that operates directly on the parameters.xml file, then you can use the [File Transform task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/file-transform?view=azure-devops#yaml-snippet) to add/replace values in your .config with tokens, and then use the [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) task to insert your variable values.

### Example:

In my sandbox I can replace the xml values in the specified sections in the quoted text above by simply adding the appropriate variable in my pipeline.

#### Given this is my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSection>
        <section name="entityFramework" />
    </configSection>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DefaultConnection"
             connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\LocalDB;FileName=Local.mdf" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
        <add key="UnobstructiveJavascriptEnabled" value="true" />
        <add key="AdminUserName" value="__AdminUserName__" />
        

<!-- Change AdminPassword in this line: --> 
        <add key="AdminPassword" value="__AdminPassword__" />


    </appSettings>
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.LocalDbConnectionFactory">
            <parameters></parameters>
        </defaultConnectionFactory>
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>    
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
    </staticContent>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>


<!-- change this value -->
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />


      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

#### And GIVEN these variables in yaml:

```
variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  AdminPassword: 'fake password'
  maxAllowedContentLength: '25'
```

#### And GIVEN this is the yaml task:

```
- task: FileTransform@1
  inputs:
    folderPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/src'
    enableXmlTransform: false
    fileType: 'xml'
    targetFiles: '*.config'
```

#### The result is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSection>
        <section name="entityFramework"/>
    </configSection>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\LocalDB;FileName=Local.mdf"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
        <add key="UnobstructiveJavascriptEnabled" value="true"/>
        <add key="AdminUserName" value="__AdminUserName__"/>


        <add key="AdminPassword" value="fake password"/>


    </appSettings>
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.LocalDbConnectionFactory">
            <parameters/>
        </defaultConnectionFactory>
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer"/>
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>    
    <system.webServer>        
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>


                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824"/>


            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
```

#### Notice the un-substituted value!!

As stated in the documentation, the value I wanted to change `<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824"/>` is unchanged b/c it is not defined by a `configSection` and is not part of the predefined nodes.

### Using the 3rd party to substitute outside the defaults

Take the same config file but change the yaml task to include a transformation to the following `transform.config`

**Given the same config file**

#### transform.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- For more information on using web.config transformation visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=125889 -->

<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
<system.webServer>    
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>


        <!-- change this value -->
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="${maxAllowedContentLength}$" xdt:Transform="Replace" />


      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

#### New task settings

```
- task: FileTransform@1
  inputs:
    folderPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/src'
    enableXmlTransform: true
    xmlTransformationRules: '-transform transform.config -xml app.config'
    fileType: 'xml'
    targetFiles: '*.config'

- task: replacetokens@3
  inputs:
    rootDirectory: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)/src'
    targetFiles: 'app.config'
    encoding: 'auto'
    writeBOM: false
    actionOnMissing: 'warn'
    keepToken: false
    tokenPrefix: '${'
    tokenSuffix: '}$'
```

#### And the results are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSection>
        <section name="entityFramework"/>
    </configSection>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\LocalDB;FileName=Local.mdf"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
        <add key="UnobstructiveJavascriptEnabled" value="true"/>
        <add key="AdminUserName" value="__AdminUserName__"/>


        <add key="AdminPassword" value="fake password"/>


    </appSettings>
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.LocalDbConnectionFactory">
            <parameters/>
        </defaultConnectionFactory>
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer"/>
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>    
    <system.webServer>        
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>


                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="25"/>


            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
```

Comment: I am so sorry for the delay in responding and thank you so much for the detailed response.  You say "there is an option to transform with a file that "tokenizes" your .config file nd then use the Replace Tokens task".   Where/what is this option?

Comment: @Joe I'm not sure what is unclear. I've linked the [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) task, and given an example of how to use it. Perhaps you are getting caught up on the word "option". That is not just a checkbox. That is a "course of action". Basically: you're going to create a transform file used to tokenize your config and then use the linked task to substitute those tokens with variable values.